# I try to install scPDSI in R studio and it cant work

Tags: r, package

- installing *source* package 'scPDSI' ...
  ** package 'scPDSI' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** using staged installation
  ** libs

> Error in system(paste(MAKE, p1(paste("-f", shQuote(makefiles))), "compilers"),  :
> 'make' not found

- removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.3.1/library/scPDSI'
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpuYkC1U/downloaded_packages/scPDSI_0.1.3.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Does anyone know how to solve this, I need to solve this for my study

I want to install this package for my study with PDSI (Palmer Drought Severity Index)

Comment: Looks like you are trying to install from source on Windows and have not installed [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools43/rtools.html). I note also that [this package](https://github.com/cran/scPDSI) has been removed from CRAN and has not been updated since 2018.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the `scPDSI` package using the following code

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/scPDSI/scPDSI_0.1.3.tar.gz", 
                 repo=NULL, type="source")
```